How come you can use a Vector3 constructor without parameters in Unity when it's a struct?
I'm a beginner to both Unity and C# but I was looking through the Unity code and I noticed that Vector3 was a struct type in Unity.
However, I was wondering why is it that I can then declare something like this:
transform.position = new Vector3();

And then also have it default to a position of (0,0,0). Isn't it the case that in C# a struct can't have a parameterless constructor? Going into Vector3.cs I also can't see anywhere that the default constructor Vector3() was initialized. I can only see two constructors, one for 3 parameters and one for 2 parameters.
Anyway, I guess my questions are:

How is Unity using a parameterless Vector3 constructor when it's using C# and .NET?
Where is the Vector3() constructor initialized to default to returning a position of (0,0,0) since I can't see a default constructor in the Vector3.cs file?


A struct in C# can (since a few versions ago) have a parameterless constructor, but even if it does not, constructing it results in it being default-initialized, i.e. new Vector3() is the same as default(Vector3). That does not have to be declared anywhere, that is how value types work in general ‒ a default value is always valid and results in all zeroes.

"a default value is always valid and results in all zeroes." - it's valid as far as the compiler is concerned, yes - but it is also common for struct types to be used as zero-overhead refinement-types that do check their internal state and will throw if it's ever detected as invalid, and that can include being default. For this reason, I hope C# adds a way to disallow default value-types in some cases. We shall see!

But where in Unity does it default the x, y, z to = 0? From what I can see it declares them as floats but doesn't assign them any value?

If you don't specify an initial value for class/struct members, it uses the default value. For floats (and all numbers, actually); it's 0.

@reetyn the difference between a class/reference type and a struct/value type is that the latter is always laid out in memory .. so saying new Vector3() basically simply reserves 12 bytes of memory (3 x sizeof(float)) and treats this memory as a Vector3 .. it will be 0,0,0 since basically all those 12 bytes have simply the default value 0

struct has always implicit parameterless constructor, as per the documentation:

Unlike a class, a struct is not permitted to declare a parameterless instance constructor. Instead, every struct implicitly has a parameterless instance constructor, which always returns the value that results from setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to null (§8.3.3). A struct can declare instance constructors having parameters.


a struct is not permitted to declare a parameterless instance constructor that should be old? Unity may not support C#10, but I think it was added there

From what I can tell, it's the default initialization behavior for structs in C#, according to the documentation.

(...) since structs are value types that cannot be null, the default
value of a struct is the value produced by setting all value type
fields to their default value and all reference type fields to null.

You can read more about it here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs#1645-default-values

In Unity, the Vector3 structure has a parameterless constructor that initializes all its components to zero. This is possible because Unity provides a default constructor for structures unless one is explicitly defined.

Where? I can't see it in the Vector3 structure it just declares x,y,z as floats but doesn't assign them a value?
